# Parent-Child Query joined to to the same table

Tags: oracle

I'm working with ORACLE

I have this table:

```
create table test (
 OFFICE varchar2(10)
,PERSON varchar2(20)
,KEY_CHIEF varchar2(10)
,FKEY_CHIEF varchar2(10)
);
```

These are the records:

> ```
> insert into test values ('Sales','Mr. Mark','10','');
> insert into test values ('Admin','Mr. Ken','','10');
> insert into test values ('Accounting','Miss. Love','','10');
> ```

I'm trying to get a query like this:

```
|OFFICE        |PERSON         |CHIEF      
|Sales         |Mr. Mark       |NULL
|Admin         |Mr. Ken        |Mr. Mark
|Accounting    |Miss. Love     |Mr. Mark
```

I'm doing this but it doesn't work, I hope u can help me please?

```
select t.office, t.person, t2.office, t2.person
     from test t
     left outer join test t2 
     ON t.KEY_CHIEF = t2.FKEY_CHIEF
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing results such as

```
Sales       Mr. Mark    Admin       Mr. Ken
Sales       Mr. Mark    Accounting  Miss. Love
Admin       Mr. Ken     Sales       Mr. Mark
Accounting  Miss. Love  Sales       Mr. Mark
```

Is because you've used an empty string as the chief key for both non-chief persons and also as a foreign key to the persons `chief`. As a result, it creates a circular dependency - Mr Mark has two chiefs, viz `Mr Ken` and `Miss Love`

Instead, you should use a unique key for each Person, and I would suggest using `NULL` to indicate that a person has no chief.

A table structure such as this might serve better

```
create table test (
 PERSONID varchar2(10),
 OFFICE varchar2(10),
 PERSON varchar2(20),
 CHIEFID varchar2(10),

 CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY(PERSONID),
 CONSTRAINT FKEY_CHIEF FOREIGN KEY (CHIEFID) REFERENCES test(PERSONID)
);

insert into test values ('10', 'Sales','Mr. Mark',null);
insert into test values ('11', 'Admin','Mr. Ken','10');
insert into test values ('12', 'Accounting','Miss. Love','10');
```

Your Query then becomes:

```
select t.office, t.person, t2.office as ChiefOffice, t2.person as ChiefName
     from test t
     left outer join test t2 
     ON t.CHIEFID = t2.PERSONID;
```

With the result

```
Office      Person      ChiefOffice  ChiefName
-----------------------------------------------
Sales       Mr. Mark    NULL         NULL
Admin       Mr. Ken     Sales        Mr. Mark
Accounting  Miss. Love  Sales        Mr. Mark
```